# Errant behavior in distribution of '.DS_Store' files

Tags: finder, network, backup, nas

I am currently using macOS Ventura. According to "About this Mac", I am using ver. 13.6.5. Like some of you, I also employ a NAS (network file server<sup>*+*</sup>) for backups and general file storage. My NAS is distributed by a company called [Synology](https://www.synology.com/). The Mac and the Synology have something in common: they both produce files that [can result in *malfunctions* in other programs/systems](https://eclecticlight.co/2021/11/27/explainer-ds_store-files/). I typically encounter these malfunctions when performing system backups with the [`rsync`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) program; e.g. `cannot delete empty folder`.

Is there a proven, reliable, method for stopping macOS from [spewing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spew) these disruptive `.DS_Store` files all over my NAS? And even though it's probably *"off-topic"* to ask in this SE, does a similar remedy exist for the files *spewed* by the Synology NAS?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with macOS Sierra (10.12), Apple has taken *extra steps* to hide the presence of `.DS_Store` files; i.e. since 10.12 they can not be seen as *hidden files*... they simply cannot be seen at all in `Finder`. I do not know why, except that this tactic seems to fit in with Apple's generally *secretive* [MO](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/modus-operandi). There has been much speculation and investigation into the details and content of the `.DS_Store` file, but AFAIK no one has completely [*"cracked the code"*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/crack+the+code) on this file.

I have [presumed innocence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presumption_of_innocence) wrt Apple's creation and long-term use of the `.DS_Store` file. I've made this assumption in ignorance of the file's function/purpose, but I ***do wish*** they would disclose their reasoning. That said, I agree that Apple's intemperate dispersion of `DS_Store` files is a ***bad thing*** as it may cause malfunctions in software/systems performing necessary or desirable functions.

Apple *implies* they have provided a [method to limit this intemperate dispersion](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102064) of `.DS_Store` files. *Unfortunately* for users, their announcement is **deceptively** worded. Note that the command contains the term `DSDontWriteNetworkStores`; if taken at face value this *implies* that Apple does not ***Write*** `.DS_Store` files. Yet in the preceding paragraph Apple writes, *"you can prevent macOS from ***reading*** .DS_Store files"*. Very [slick](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/slick) piece of writing!

[Apple's announcement](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102064) contains further ambiguities. It says "`for browsing network folders such as Server Message Block (SMB) shares`". No mention is made of other network file systems; e.g. [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) or [SSHFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS). I have not tested these other network file systems here as Synology uses SMB by default. And speaking of testing, results of my testing of ***the Apple Solution for `.DS_Store`*** follows:

##### IAW [Apple's online instructions (published Feb 29 of 2024)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102064):

```shell
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores -bool TRUE
```

##### Test the Command:

Since Apple doesn't actually tell us much, we should verify the setting. After the `write` above, let's now do a `read`:

```shell
defaults read com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores
1
```

Huh - `1`... I wondered what that meant in *"Apple-speak"*, so went a bit further to verify:

```shell
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores -bool FALSE
defaults read com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores
0
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores -bool TRUE
defaults read com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores
1
```

So - Apparently TRUE == 1, and FALSE == 0

Now, just for grins we'll try this with a different user - a member of the Administrator group:

```shell
seamus@fumier ~ % su sdemora
Password: 
sdemora@fumier ~ % defaults read com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores
2024-03-23 21:21:24.357 defaults[33484:4740417] 
The domain/default pair of (com.apple.desktopservices, DSDontWriteNetworkStores) does not exist 

# surprising! but apparently the default value does not exist until it is written! 

sdemora@fumier ~ % defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores -bool TRUE
sdemora@fumier ~ % defaults read com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores
1
```

And so, in conclusion we see that the command syntax works as claimed. But let's see if the command actually stops distribution of the `.DS_Store` files.

##### Does Apple's Command Actually Limit Writing `.DS_Store` Files?

I have set up a small demonstration using `rsync` on a Synology NAS (DSM ver 7.2-64570 Update 3). The demonstration involves a small folder with 2 subfolders, and a dozen files on the local drive of my Mac (aka *fumier*). These local files are the **SOURCE** in this `rsync` demo. I `rsync` these local files/folders to the `rsync daemon` running on the Synology NAS; this copies the files to Synology's file system. The Synology server's filesystem is the **DESTINATION** in this demo.

***IOW***, this is a very typical (but simplified) configuration for backing up one's local drive to a network file system using `rsync`.

Following is the script I run on my Mac to perform the actual `rsync` backup:

```bash
#!/opt/local/bin/bash
PATH=/opt/local/libexec/gnubin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
cd '/Users/jmoore/scripts/rsync-bkup'

SRC_Demo='/Users/seamus/RsyncDemo/'
DST_Demo='rsync://seamus@SynologyNAS-1/backups/fumier/Rsync_Demo'
rsync -rlAtgoDiv --password-file=./pwd-f $SRC_Demo $DST_Demo

exit 0
```

After running the script above, following is the Finder view of the `rsync'd` files on the SynologyNAS:

[image: Finder view]

Now for the moment of truth... did Apple's `defaults` command prevent the propogation of `.DS_Store` files from the Mac to the NAS? Since we can't actually see `.DS_Store` files in Finder, we'll need to use something else - the `find` command will work for this:

```shell
seamus@fumier /Volumes/backups/fumier % find . -name '.DS_Store' -print
./Rsync_Demo/.DS_Store
./Rsync_Demo/RsyncDemoA/folderA/folderA-1/.DS_Store
./Rsync_Demo/RsyncDemoA/folderA/folderA-2/.DS_Store
./Rsync_Demo/RsyncDemoA/folderA/.DS_Store
./Rsync_Demo/RsyncDemoA/.DS_Store
./Rsync_Demo/RsyncDemoB/folderB/folderB-1/.DS_Store
./Rsync_Demo/RsyncDemoB/folderB/folderB-2/.DS_Store
./Rsync_Demo/RsyncDemoB/folderB/.DS_Store
./Rsync_Demo/RsyncDemoB/.DS_Store
```

What we see above is proof positive that Apple's `DSDontWriteNetworkStores` command **did not inhibit** the propagation of `.DS_Store` files from the Mac to the Synology file server.

##### *The Verdict:*

##### Apple's `defaults` command **did not** prevent the propagation of `.DS_Store` files

This is fairly disappointing - even considering that "it's Apple". You're free to draw your own conclusions. A few other points to ponder:

1. Perhaps Apple considers this to be a *"non-covered"* form of network connection?
2. If you actually *read* [Apple's announcement](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102064), you may note the following statement: *"you can prevent macOS from **reading** .DS_Store files on SMB shares"*. Odd that - naming a command to prevent *reading* as *"DSDont**Write**NetworkStores"*!?
3. As it turns out, Apple's online instructions for limiting the spew of `.DS_Store` have been circulating for [more than 10 years](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=DSDontWriteNetworkStores), discussed in [reputable forums](https://eclecticlight.co/2021/11/27/explainer-ds_store-files/), including ***hundreds*** of [Q&A here on SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=.DS_Store). The fact that Apple re-published it on Feb 29 of 2024 is puzzling, but not surprising in its arrogance.
4. Or... perhaps I overlooked something? If so - please let me hear from you!

Comment: I would expect `rsync` to syncs all files (including .DS_Store) - I am not an rsync expert. The `com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores` applies to Finder/desktopservices writing to SMB stores.